# Need solution for redirecting the users to the site after credit card payment through Paypal

Tags: joomla, paypal, virtuemart

I am using Paypal plugin in my virtuemart 2.0.8 for Joomla 2.5. When any user is making payment via credit card, after completion of their payment they are getting option to create their Paypal account or a link is given to redirect to mysite.com and the user gets stuck there.

How will the credit card user get redirected automatically to my site once the payment is made? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard PayPal plugin only uses the basic PayPal service which doesn't "automatically" return the user to the merchant, it just presents them with the link to click.

I believe you would have to use PayPal Pro (which keeps the user on your site) — looking at the [Virtuemart Extensions directory there is a PayPal Pro plugin](http://extensions.virtuemart.net/?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&sobi2Id=172&Itemid=2).

*By the way you really should update your Virtuemart installation as there have been dozens of bug fixes since 2.0.8.*

Comment: Thanks for the comments but it is not true that standard PayPal Plugin only provides basic services because previously I was using the same PayPal when my website was on Joomla 1.5 and the auto redirection was working perfectly. But as I upgraded the website to Joomla 2.5 it stopped working. I think some settings have been changed. Please advice on how can I make it work again in a similar way.

Comment: Were you using VM2 on Joomla 1.5? The payment plugins for VM2 were completely re-written and their behaviour is different (that's why we wrote our own for the last 10 VM2 site we built over the last year).

Also as Brent says it varies with the basic PayPal based on the users actions.

Comment: I am using VM2 in my joomla 2.5 site and the paypal plugin is working properly. But I only need the solution for credit card user to auto redirect back to my site once they have completed the payment. Please provide some solution for it.

Comment: Brent & I have told you what we know (and what PayPal says and does) both things you could have found out with 2 seconds of Google. There is little more we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Paypal payments standard, it's a hit or miss situation. If the user does not log in to their Paypal account to make the payment, then they cannot be automatically redirected after they finish the transaction, they best they can do is click the link.

If they do log in, then you can redirect them, but you have to set it up in your Paypal account. Details here - https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside

Also, @cppl is correct, you need to update your site, particularly when you do e-commerce. The most common reason sites are hacked is out of date extensions or Joomla. Keep everything updated, it's easy insurance to keep your site safe.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but it is not true that standard PayPal Plugin only provides basic services because previously I was using the same PayPal when my website was on Joomla 1.5 and the auto redirection was working perfectly. But as I upgraded the website to Joomla 2.5 it stopped working. I think some settings have been changed. Please advice on how can I make it work again in a similar way.

Comment: If you are using Paypal standard, then auto return is not handled by the plugin it's a Paypal setting. This is from Paypal -

How Auto Return Works:
* If the buyer pays with a PayPal account, they are automatically taken back to the site.

* If the buyer pays with the Credit Card Option, they are taken to the receipt page where PayPal gives them the chance to print out a receipt. This is a legal requirement. After that, the buyer must click on the "Return to Merchant" link in order to return to the site.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I am not agree with you that it is a legal requirement as before upgrading the website to Joomla 2.5 and virtuemart 2 it was working fine as required and after upgrading it stopped working so there is some issue with it only. So just wanted to know what is the issue with it so that I can resolve it. Any comments?

Comment: You don't have to agree with me, I am simply posting what is on the Paypal website. The redirection is handled by Paypal, you have to do it their way. Did you read the information at the link? It's pretty clear about how this works.